# How to correctly merge the value in the columns, in the case of using the widget type the Value map, with QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, merge

Trying to do work that was previously done in ArcGIS. There is a table when filling 4 columns, these values are added in the Sum column.
[image]

In QGIS, I decided to use the Value Map for fields

[image]
For the Sum field, I use the following expression

[image]

But as a result, I lose zeros
before number
[image]

Where did I go wrong and how do I get values with zeros when field type  is real and SUM field is string?

Comment: Try to use the [`lpad("FILL",2,'0')`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#lpad).